# C language Hang man game, Loop problem, counter not working and connecting the random word with the guessed letter via a scanf statement

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, if-statement, counter

So some information, I am making a hangman game, that get's a random word from an array, which then that random word is masked and printed as '_' to show the user how many letters the random word has.

A typical hangman is you have a number of tries and once you reach a certain threshold you lose. This is shown in the code by a print that prints the hangman slowly building with each increase in counter.

Now the issue lies in I have no idea how to connect these concepts. How scanf code will interact with the random word, and counter. Especially since the masked word is in int, I tried using the char m, for loop;

```
int counter = 0; answer != m; counter++
```

but nothing happens instead it just outputs the print for the "You win!" statement despite only putting in one letter.

I even tried;

```
int counter = 0; answer != 'q'; counter++
```

So I can see if when I input a letter not q if it will start building the hang man, but even then it still prints out "You win!"

Also tried;

```
for (int counter = 0; counter >= 7; counter++)
```

So it has to continue counting until greater or equal to 7, yet still nothing.

Any tips?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10

int main()
{
    //randomwordgenerator
    char word[ARRAY_SIZE][200] = { 
        "tiger", "lion", "elephant", "zebra", "horse", 
        "camel", "deer", "crocodile", "rabbit", "cat" 
    };

    int x = 0;
    srand(time(0));

    x = rand() % ARRAY_SIZE;

    system("pause"); //will pause the rand function

    // masking and unmasking word
    char m = strlen(word[x]); //will count the number of letters of the random word
    // int mask[200]{};
    int mask[200]{};
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) { //loop until all leters are masked
        mask[i] = '_';
        printf("%c ", mask[i]);
    }

    //Introduction
    printf("\nHey! Can you please save me? \n");
    printf(" O\n/|\\ \n/ \\ \n");

    //Ask for answer
    printf(
        "\n"
        "Type a letter to guess the word and save me. Here are some tips!\n" 
        "1) The '_' above are how many letters make up the word, isn't that neat!\n"
        "2) The letters are case sensitive so please pick lower case or I might die\n" 
        "3) Have fun! \nNow with that out of the way please type in your guess; "
    );

    char answer;
    scanf_s("%c", &answer);

    //loop w counter
    for (int counter = 0; answer != 'q'; counter++) {
        if (counter == 1) {
            printf("\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 2) {
            printf("\n+\n|\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 3) {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 4) {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 5) {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|   |\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 6) {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|   |\n|  / \\ \n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 7) {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|  /| \n|  / \\ \n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 8) {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|  /|\\ \n|  / \\ \n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 9) {
            printf("\nReally left me hanging there buddy");
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            printf("\nThanks for saving me!");
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you storing the result of strlen() in a char?

Comment: Because I defined the `char word` so I continued using char even for m. Is there a problem with it? Should I change the data type?

Comment: Are you compiling with a C++ compiler? If you're using a C compiler this should fail on `#include <string>`. This should also be causing you problems: `int mask[200]{};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see several problems here:

Your `for` loop initializes and updates `counter` but tests against `answer`. This could be simplified by simply looping while counter is < 10.

This `for` loop also initializes counter to 0 but this falls in the `else` of your loop body, printing the win message.

You have a return 0 at the end of your loop, making it exit the program directly after 1 iteration.

Next, you are not updating your `answer` inside the loop (but I am assuming you had problems before so you did not go that far yet). You will need to call scanf inside to update the answer. There's a lot to be improved upon but I think this can help you with your current problems. I tried to not change your code much.

```c
for (int counter = 1; counter < 10; counter++) {
        scanf_s("%c", &answer);

        // you can handle the answer logic here
        if (answer ...)
        {

        }

        if (counter == 1)
        {
            printf("\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 2)
        {
            printf("\n+\n|\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 3)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|\n|\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 4)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 5)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|   |\n|\n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 6)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|   |\n|  / \\ \n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 7)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|  /| \n|  / \\ \n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 8)
        {
            printf("\n+---+\n|   |\n|   O\n|  /|\\ \n|  / \\ \n|\n=========");
        }
        else if (counter == 9)
        {
            printf("\nReally left me hanging there buddy");
            break;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("\nThanks for saving me!");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Jacky thank you so much! This fixed literally everything, the loop is actually looping and printing out the stick man. I only need to figure out the logic now, since when I tried the loops seemed to repeat twice and ignore the answer despite it being a letter in the word.

Comment: Hello again, just a question, how would I handle making the system understand that the scanf i.e answer, is to find one letter of the word? Because right now it's only understanding if I input the whole word.

Comment: @Ocelotter Hello, this is a pretty vague question. I can help you, but this comment section is not the best place for longer exchanges. Do you have Discord (or any similar app)?

Comment: Yes i do; Ñ ö ö d ) è#2927